# How to pass/output a whitespace \x20 character to docx

Tags: python, whitespace, python-docx

I'm using **python-docx** to create and write to a docx file. My application would write one word at a time. I used

```
p.add_run(res.decode('unicode_escape'));
```

to write the unicode words, one at a time. However whenever there was a white-space character in/between `add_run()` would fail miserably and I would have concatenated words.

I tried following:

1. `repr(res)` works but it would output the unnecessary '(quote) characters
2. `res = r'\x20'` no effect
3. `res = ''' '''` no effect
4. `res = r' '`    no effect

I used the above expressions to assign a `whitespace` to `res` variable and then tried to append it to current paragraph with
`p.add_run(res)`

Finally I changed the way I was writing the text. Instead of writing single words/chunks, I collected a complete line and then write it to document.

*Though I have solved the problem*, I would still like to get insights into the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A run is a sequence of characters that all have the same character formatting. In general, you would write all the text sharing that same formatting into the same run to avoid incurring the run "container" overhead (about 20 bytes each) where you don't need it. So the solution you ended up with sounds like the recommended approach.

But addressing the missing whitespace question, if you wanted "Mary had a little lamb." and it was all in the same font (considering bold or italic to be a different font from regular), you would use:

```
p.add_run("Mary had a little lamb.")
```

If you did this:

```
p.add_run("Mary")
p.add_run("had")
p.add_run("a")
p.add_run("little")
p.add_run("lamb.")
```

You would get what you asked for, which is "Maryhadalittlelamb.", because you failed to provide the leading and/or trailing whitespace you wanted. Adding a run does not try to figure out where you want whitespace, it just does what you ask.

If instead you did:

```
p.add_run("Mary ")
p.add_run("had")
p.add_run(" a ")
p.add_run("little")
p.add_run(" lamb.")
```

You would get "Mary had a little lamb."

If you post an example of actual input and the specific unexpected output perhaps I can offer more by way of explanation.

Regarding the 20 bytes of overhead, adding separate runs containing the text 'foo' and 'bar' produces XML like this:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>foo</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:t>bar</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Whereas a single run containing the text 'foobar' produces this XML, 22 characters shorter if you neglect the newlines and indentation whitespace used for pretty-printing it here (which would be removed on saving):

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>foobar</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Some of this would be compressed out because the .docx file is a Zip archive, I suppose it's just my engineering habit toward minimizing waste that would make me look for the more economical solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.     `run "container" overhead (about 20 bytes each)` Where/How did you find that? The example you asked is updated in questions.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for the 20-byte overhead. I'm still not getting just what you're trying to do though, in particular why you're decoding. You can add a run that contains only whitespace with `add_run('  ')`. I'm not getting what the difficulty is. That's why I suggested saying "I put in this string and I got out that string" so we don't have to imagine what inputs produced what outputs from your generalized description. If you give us concrete examples I think I could make sense of it for you.